# webpack-dev-server injects CSS webpack doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, webpack

I'm new to webpack and I'm facing an issue while trying to build a simple webpage.
While I don't have problems when using `webpack-dev-server`, when I build my application with `webpack` I don't see the CSS inside the `index.html` file.

Here is the `webpack.conf.js`:

```
var path = require( "path" );

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin' );

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        index: path.join( __dirname, "src", "index.js" )
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join( __dirname, "dist" ),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    devServer: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 9000,
        writeToDisk: true
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: ['file-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.styl$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    "css-loader",   // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    "stylus-loader" // compiles Stylus to CSS
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin( {
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: path.join( __dirname, "src", "index.html" ),
            inject: true
        } ),
    ]
};
```

This is the `index.js`:

```
import "./css/index.styl";
import "./css/graphics.styl";
import "./js/polyfills.js"
import "./js/manager.js"

console.log( "TEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEST" );
```

Here the `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="graphicsContainer" class="graphics-container">
        <%=require('./assets/images/barca_onde.svg')%>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I run the dev mode with this command:

```
./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config /app/webpack.config.js --mode development --color --watch
```

While the build command I use is this:

```
./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config /app/webpack.config.js --mode production --color
```

Both commands don't show any error, but the first generates the `bundle.js`, the inline SVG, the CSS code and injects them in the `index.html` while the second only generates `bundle.js` and the SVG and injects them in `index.html` leaving the CSS out.

What am I missing? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your configuration isn't set up to write your compiled CSS to a file. The injection of style only happens in development mode, which is why you aren't seeing it when you build in production mode.

If you're using the latest major release of webpack (which is 4 as of this answer), you'll want to use [`MiniCssExtractPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/). It replaces `style-loader` in your configuration.

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

// ...

{
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: devMode ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
      chunkFilename: devMode ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css',
    }),
  ],
  rules: [
    {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: { hmr: devMode },
          },
          "css-loader",
          "stylus-loader"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For prior major releases of webpack, see [ExtractTextWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So should I import the CSS in the index.html by manually writing the <link> tag or will it be added automatically?

Comment: I've figured it out myself! I will study the documentation to see how to inject the CSS directly in the index.html